# AWS S3 File upload in NodeJS taking longer than it should

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When using aws-sdk module for NodeJS, I am noticing uploads are taking longer than they should for the size I am uploading. The upload is taking 2 seconds for a 100kB of data.

The function below accepts a base64 encoded png, converts it to a buffer and uploads to S3.

```
var getBufferFromPngBase64 = function(pngBase64) {
  var dataBase64, dataBinary;

  dataBase64 = pngBase64.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, '');
  dataBase64 = dataBase64.replace(/ /g, '+');
  dataBinary = new Buffer(dataBase64, 'base64');

  return dataBinary;
};

var uploadAwsSdk = function(pngData) {
  var start = new Date().getTime(),
      pngBuffer = getBufferFromPngBase64(pngData);

  s3Obj.putObject({
    ContentType: 'image/png',
    Body: pngBuffer,
    ContentEncoding: 'base64',
    ContentLength: pngBuffer.length,
    Key: "foo.png"
  }, function(err, data) {
    //done
  });
};
```

I have tried

- Both upload and putObject functions
- Knox module
- Multiple versions of NodeJS

I thought this was just standard slow S3 times, however it uploads much faster when its a 1 byte file, so I'm not sure what's going on. Is this just normal for S3, or am I using NodeJS for something I shouldn't be?

Comment: Have you tried timing your get buffer function and see if the bottleneck comes from there?

Comment: Have you tried uploading the file using AWS CLI to make sure that the upload delay is connected to your node code and not to your network in general?

Comment: @YaronIdan looks like the time is similar for AWS CLI. Shocking it takes 2+ seconds to upload a 100kB file, even in EC2.

Comment: It might your network connection or just the price of opening and closing the handle (although you've mentioned shorter response times for 1b files). Any way, on my servers the upload is almost instant, even with bigger files. Are your ec2 servers and s3 buckets in the same region?